# Include Google maps so that I dynamically can change the location via admincenter

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

I included Google maps to a company website under location. Now the problem is, whenever the company wants to change the location it would have to edit the PHP / HTML file where the google maps include is written. I want to do this automatically via PHP and MySQL, I just want to offer a formula where the administrator of the website has to put in an adress and it click save so that it changes the location automatically in the database and I can call the data from the database on the page where the actual google maps iframe is included.

I googled so hard but I could only find Google Map Generators which were offering the final iframe code but no example on how they did the formula to realize this.

I found a javascript code that helped me, but the version of google maps is outdated and so are the parameters which don't provide the option of height and with only latitude and longitude I land somewhere completly wrong.

Where can I find tutorials on how to build my matter?

Thanks in advance

Comment: google maps loads via a url, you can hack up that url anyway you want. search terms, lat/long, blah blah blah. so save the individual parameters in your db and stuff them into the gmaps url when you build your page.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, I will try that asap. Do you know a script that calculates the lat / long that has been given just an adress string? (would make it easier)

Comment: there's an API for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Google Maps API. Pull the company address and use the `Geocoder` method to return the lat/lng and then use the lat/lng in a `Marker` overlay or whatever other overlay type you may want to use. 
See.... https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference